# Present Sequence as a sum of 2 squares

Tags: c#, loops, binary-search

I was solving a [CodeWars task](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5e4bb05b698ef0001e3344bc/train/csharp) and faced a problem.

In it you are given the array of numbers, which length is a multiple of 4, you need to visualise it as a (`x1^2 + x2^2`) * (`x3^2 + x4^2`) .... * (`xn^2 + xn+1^2`).

Calculate the result of this and find 2 numbers, which squares in sum, gives the result of initial sequance.
For example, you are given an array of ( 2, 1, 3, 4):
`(2^2 + 1^2) * (3^2 + 4^2) = 125;`

2 numbers, which squares in sum will give 125, is 2 and 11 because 4 + 121 = 125;

I wrote the code and it works with most of examples, but when i use big arrays such as
`(3, 9, 8, 4, 6, 8, 7, 8, 4, 8, 5, 6, 6, 4, 4, 5)` in result i receive `(0,0);`

I can't get the problem, help me pls and if u can use simplified english cause i am from Russia.
Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Collections.Generic;


 public class ProdSeq
    {
        public static BigInteger[] solve(int[] arr)
        {
            bool simplified = false;
            var result = new BigInteger[2];
            var index = 0;
           

            BigInteger sequenceSum = 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i+=2)
                sequenceSum *= arr[i] * arr[i] + arr[i + 1] * arr[i + 1];
            
             if (sequenceSum >= 1000000)
            {
                sequenceSum /= 10000;
                simplified = true;
            }

            var list = new List<BigInteger>();

            for (BigInteger i = 0; i <= (BigInteger)Math.Sqrt((double)sequenceSum + 1); i++)
                list.Add(BigInteger.Multiply(i, i));
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                var second = sequenceSum - list[i];
                  index = list.BinarySearch(second);
                if (index > -1)
                {
                    if (simplified)
                    {
                        result[0] = (BigInteger)(Math.Sqrt((double)list[i]) * 100);
                        result[1] = (BigInteger)(Math.Sqrt((double)list[index]) * 100);
                        break;
                    }
                    
                   
                        result[0] = (BigInteger)(Math.Sqrt((double)list[i]));
                        result[1] = (BigInteger)(Math.Sqrt((double)list[index]));
                    break;
                }
            }

            
            Console.WriteLine($"A: {result[0]} B: {result[1]}");
             return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you sure to have always a solution?

Comment: yup, codewars states so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems your error is coming from this line:

```
        for (int i = 0; i <= (int)Math.Sqrt((double)sequenceSum + 1); i++)
            list.Add(BigInteger.Multiply(i , i));
```

you have to use [Biginteger.Multiply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.multiply?view=net-6.0) method

`result = 302400  and  29092800`   (lot of solutions i think)

Comment: Yup, it works now, but i am still getting timeouts with bigger example. For example, (5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 2, 4, 7, 6, 5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 9, 6, 5, 7, 9, 5, 8, 9, 6, 8, 4, 9, 2, 5, 5, 3, 9, 7, 9, 2, 6, 3, 2) dropes me a timeout.

Comment: I have edited my code. You can look at a new version now

Comment: .i have resolved your problem of result [0,0]..and you change your question..timeout is another problem... i suggest you to close the first question to avoid confusion and open another with th timeout problem...